# Можно ли передать тип данных строкой?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Допустим, `char *typeofdata = {"int"}`, или что-то вроде этого. 
У меня есть шаблонный класс `Arr` и я передаю тип в котором нужно работать в основную функцию. Написал меню, в котором, например, `1 = int, 2 = double, 3 = float`. Можно ли подать тип данных как-то так: `Arr<typeofdata> myarr`?

```
int action = menu();
switch (action) {
    case 1: {
        Array<int> myarr;
        myarr.setelem();
        myarr.show();
        myarr.searchzeroelems();
        myarr.sumofelems();
        myarr.sorting();
        myarr.show();
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        Array<double> myarr;
        myarr.setelem();
        myarr.show();
        myarr.searchzeroelems();
        myarr.sumofelems();
        myarr.sorting();
        myarr.show();
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        Array<float> myarr;
        myarr.setelem();
        myarr.show();
        myarr.searchzeroelems();
        myarr.sumofelems();
        myarr.sorting();
        myarr.show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам это? Скорее всего, вам это не нужно, а нужно просто протянуть нужный тип до той точки, где он задаётся.

Comment: Ну у меня при каждом типе данных одни и те же операции, а кода выходит в 3 раза больше, потому-что нужно копировать одни и те же функции для каждой ситуации.

Comment: тогда может написать шаблонную функцию?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это сделать. Вот, вызываю я меню, получаю число, по которому дальше должен вызывать, например, Arr<double> myarr, а как к этому функцию написать, я не знаю.

Comment: @MovieZ: Если вы не дадите код, нам сложно будет вам помочь.

Comment: @VladD: Добавил, как  приходится делать сейчас.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<typename T>
void Do()
{
    Array<T> myarr; 
    myarr.setelem();
    myarr.show();
    myarr.searchzeroelems();
    myarr.sumofelems();
    myarr.sorting();
    myarr.show();
}
```

```
int action = menu();
switch (action)
{
case 1:
    Do<int>();
    break; 
case 2: 
    Do<double>();
    break; 
case 3: 
    Do<float>();
    break; 
}
```